# Shortest-path, 2 weight functions

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, bellman-ford

The question goes like this:
A directed graph G = (V,E) is given, two vertices s,t, and two weight functions w1, w2.
There are no negative weighted cycles in G (by both w1 and w2).
I need to describe an algorithm that finds the shortest-path from s to t by w2, among the given shortest-path**s** from s to t.

I've found this:
[FInding All Shortest Paths Between Two Vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497219/finding-all-shortest-paths-between-two-vertices)
but the answers seem pretty vauge to me.

I have no idea how to solve this (even a lame one).
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could just use BFS

Comment: @SamG-H can u be more specific? I need the path to be the shortest by both w1 and w2 so i can't see how can i do it without using Bellman-Ford.

Comment: Could you explain your question more clearly please. I don't think I get it. :/

Comment: @SukritKalra The question gives me already the shortest-paths from s to t by the weight function w1. among these paths, i need to find the shortest-path from s to t by the weigh function w2. meaning: i need to find the shortest-path from s to t by both w1 & w2. apparently, i think, the shortest-paths by w1 that already given, should make the algorithm easier.

Comment: Assuming there are `x` number of paths with a cost `X` (which is minimum among all the possible paths), then you can just apply the weight function `w2` over each of the `x` paths and compute the minimum. So, for example, a path from `s -> t = s -> d -> t`, then calculate the weight using `w2(s, d) + w2(d, t)`. Do this for all the `x` paths and get the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to make `w2` important - but not enough to affect thew outcome of `w1`.

Let `SUM2` be the sum of `w2` on all edges: `SUM2 = Sum { w2(e) | e in E }`, and `min{w1} = min { w1(e) | e in E }` (minimal value according to `w1`)

Based on this, create your new weight function:

```
w(e) = w1(e) + w2(e)/min{w1}*(SUM2+1)
```

Now, given all shortest paths according to `w1` - it is obvious why shortest paths according to `w2` will be favored among them.

On the other hand, `w2` is not 'strong' enough to overcome the importance of `w1` and dominate, since note that the combined sum of ALL edges according to `w2` is now less than a single node in `w1`

Use the above `w` with any shortest path algorithm to get your desired shortest path.